# Solaris audio API

Tags: c, api, audio, solaris

How to write a `c` function to record and play voice on `Solaris`. Which api usually used to play and record voice in Solaris like we have the `WaveIn`/`WaveOut` APIs in Windows.

Comment: At the moment, this question doesn't seem well suited to StackOverflow's [Q&A format](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Could you try and refine it to a more specific question?

Comment: Getting better - my comment would now be that it's two questions: "what is the best audio API", which isn't a good question for SO and "How can I write a function to record and play back a voice" which is a better question.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris and must UNIXes use OSS (although it's possible also to use ALSA on linux, and Darwin is special as usual).

Answer (score 1):

In part it depends on the Solaris version in question.   Solaris 11.1 and later now include [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio), but for older releases there's mainly the [low level audio device API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5177/audio-7i.html#scrolltoc) with not much in the way of bundled higher level API's (though you can probably build some open source libraries on top of them, such as PulseAudio).

Comment: Question has two part, how to write a c function to record and play voice and the API name. This answered the second part.